# Trying to connect to sql server from an electron app but port not found error

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, electron

I am trying to connect to sql server from an electron app :

```
const sql = require('mssql');


const config = {
    server: 'localhost\\DESKTOP-N83KUSU',
    user: 'ashraf1',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'sampleDB',
    port: 1433,
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true,
    }
};
function connectToServer(){
sql.connect(config, (err)=> {
    if(err) {return console.log(err)}
    console.log('connected');
})
}

connectToServer();
```

but I get this error:

[image]

I have enabled TCP/IP and SQL server Browser is running. I searched a lot but didn't find a solution that works. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Althought I have no experience with node.js, this might be typo: `post: 1433`

Comment: I fixed the typo, but still gets the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

server should be localhost, remove the system name.
server: 'localhost',

Comment: Wow. I searched all night, but this simple answer worked. Thank you so much.